# How to JOIN on my Result Set and a Third Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, db2

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a JOIN where I return all the records from my Result set (query 1) below where `a.ssan = c.ssn`:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
b.timec 

FROM Lib1.Table1 a, Lib1.Table2 b 

WHERE 
a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'P2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131206 AND 
(a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or 
a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or 
a.city <> b.city or 
a. state <> b.state or 
a.zip <> b.zip)
```

**Table C fields:**

```
SSN
DATEC
TIMEC
PRINT_OLD
PRINT_NEW
```

I'm generating mail merge documents for NEW and OLD Addresses to alert members of an address change made on their account. When the NEW Address Letters are made, I run an insert on `TABLEC` setting the values of all the fields except `PRINT_OLD`. Example data would be:

```
SSN: 123456789; 
DATEC: 20131206; 
TIMEC: 133000; 
PRINT_NEW: 2013-12-06-13.30.00.965000; 
PRINT_OLD: NULL;
```

Then several days later, when going to print the OLD Address letters, 
I need to run the first query above combined with a `JOIN` on T`TABLEC` to display those records that the PRINT_OLD field is *NULL*, denoting the NEW Address Letter has been printed already for that day, but the OLD Address Letter has not.

Can anyone help me with this matter? I'm not the strongest when it comes to Database queries.

Comment: You have several databases tagged, but which type of database are you trying to do this on?

Comment: I suppose I was trying to tag where my question could potentially be of use in. I am on this matter indeed on an IBM Midrange System. I figured that by tagging more databases that could potentially have my topic applied towards, the matter would also be received by a wider number of members and perhaps yield a quicker response.

Comment: Well, that's true, you do reach a wider audience.  But solutions on one engine are not always portable to another, even sometimes within different DB2 platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableC c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a.memno,
    a.NAME,
    a.addr1,
    a.addr2,
    a.city,
    a.STATE,
    a.zip,
    a.sex,
    a.lname,
    a.ssan,
    b.addr1 AS old_addr1,
    b.addr2 AS old_addr2,
    b.city AS old_city,
    b.STATE AS old_state,
    b.zip AS old_zip,
    b.timec
  FROM Lib1.Table1 a
  INNER JOIN Lib1.Table2 b ON a.memno = b.memno
  WHERE b.groupid = 'P2'
    AND b.type = 'B' AND b.datec = 20131206
    AND (
      a.addr1 <> b.addr1 OR a.addr2 <> b.addr2
      OR a.city <> b.city OR a.STATE <> b.STATE
      OR a.zip <> b.zip)
  ) a ON a.ssan = c.ssn
WHERE c.print_old IS NULL
```

Note: I also changed your JOIN to an explicit INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty close, but I don't need to show the fields from `TABLEC`, only the values returned from the inner query between `TABLEA` and `TABLEB`.

Comment: Then it's just change SELECT * to SELECT a.*

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? Example: SELECT a.* FROM TableC?

Comment: Yes. because you are doing a INNER JOIN between tablec and that big query you had is called `a` now (see the second to last line).

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic. Did that get you what you were looking for?

Comment: I do believe it did, thanks! :) My query experience is limited to very simple select statements, so stuff like this easily confuses me.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic. This is a simple join, but instead of a full table you get the results from a different query. It's simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to your reference to Lib1 and Lib2, I am assuming you are on an IBM midrange system, correct?

I take it that memno is unique in table1, and that {memno, groupid, type, datec} is unique in tableb.

```
 SELECT a.memno, 
        a.name, 
        a.addr1, 
        a.addr2, 
        a.city, 
        a.state, 
        a.zip, 
        a.sex, 
        a.lname, 
        a.ssan, 
        b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
        b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
        b.city as old_city, 
        b.state as old_state, 
        b.zip as old_zip,
        b.datec, 
        b.timec, 
        c.PRINT_OLD
        c.PRINT_NEW
   FROM Lib1.Table1 a
   JOIN Lib1.Table2 b   
           ON a.memno = b.memno
          and b.datec = 20131206
          AND (a.addr1, a.addr2, a.city, a.state, a.zip)
           <> (b.addr1, b.addr2, b.city, b.state, b.zip)
   JOIN Lib1.TableC c
           ON c.ssn = a.ssan
          and c.datec = b.datec
          and c.timec = b.timec
   WHERE c.PRINT_OLD is NULL                   
     and b.groupid = 'P2' 
     and b.type = 'B'
     and b.datec = 20131206
```

I suspect this is a bit closer to what you are looking for, and shows some different techniques.